# Husky pre-commit not running until after commit

Tags: git, npm, npm-scripts, husky

Desired result: when I commit, prior to committing, run `npm run build`, which will generate some new files. I want those files to be added to the commit.

The current state of affairs: when I commit, it runs `npm run build` which generates files. And after the commit goes in, I have some staged changes.

I'm working with Solidity (and Forge) + npm. My repo is here if you wanna try: https://github.com/otterspace-xyz/otterspace-contracts

1. checkout a new branch `test-branch`
2. go to `Badges.sol` and add a variable   `string private test;`
3. save `Badges.sol`, run `git add .`
4. `git commit -m "commit to test husky"`
5. run `git status`

I expect that you'll see: `modified:   out/Badges.sol/Badges.json` which makes sense (I guess). It seems like `npm run build` runs but it's not adding the resulting files to the commit.

Comment: From the Git side of things, I will say only that it's not wise to attempt to *modify what will be committed* in a pre-commit hook. The hook should only *verify* that what is to be committed is correct, and produce an error if not. If you'd like to modify-then-commit, write your own non-Git command that does that: this command will verify and/or fix, then `git add`, then `git commit --no-verify` since there's no need to re-verify at this point.

Comment: There are long and mostly boring reasons *why* "modify what is to be committed in the pre-commit hook" is a bad idea in general, and they'll allow you to decide when it's OK and when it's bad, but by inverting the order—verify, *then* add and commit; don't add-and-almost-commit-and-then-verify—you make the whole problem go away. It's like putting on the condom at the right time, instead of at the very last possible second.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `git add .` in the husky hook, manually. IIRC this was a change from way back around version 3 or 4 (it's been a while). And while I agree with torek's comments in principle, this is a major use case of Husky, so it's reasonable to expect a Husky user to be familiar with the risks of modifying code in a precommit.